# Loading a font from a file to use in a P5.JS dom element

Tags: javascript, fonts, p5.js

I'm currently having trouble using custom fonts within p5.js dom. I can load the font into a var but have no idea how to style a specific element with that var.

This is what I've tried...

```
var robotoReg = loadFont("Roboto-Regular.ttf");
document.getElementById("mStockOne").style.fontFamily = "robotoReg";
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to store the font in a global variable :

```
var myFont, fontReady = false;

function fontRead(){
    fontReady = true; }

function preload() {
    myFont = loadFont("./fonts/MyfontFile.ttf", fontRead); } //replace with correct path

function setup() {
    createCanvas(720, 400);
    doyourSetup(); }

function draw() {
    background(255);
    if (fontReady) {
        textFont(myFont);
        text("Hello World!", 10, 30);
    }
 }
```

Sorry for the incorrect formatting im on mobile

Comment: Thank you for your timely response! I actually ended up creating a link element and loading it with Google Fonts    var newStyle = document.createElement('link');
  var url = new URL("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto");
  newStyle.href = url;
  newStyle.rel = "stylesheet";
  document.head.appendChild(newStyle);

Comment: Is there any drawbacks/advantages to each?

Comment: @NicholasSiebenaller i think its faster to load from file but there isn't much difference really

Comment: @NicholasSiebenaller If this answer was helpful you should consider marking it as accepted by clicking the tick on the left hand side of this answer, have a nice day :)

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question. You're just drawing to the canvas, not setting the font of an external dom element.

Comment: Also, revenge downvoting isn't cool. By downvoting a correct answer, you're making it more difficult for the OP to get help. And if you aren't on this site to help people, why are you here?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is answered in [the P5.js reference](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/loadFont):

> You can also use the string name of the font to style other HTML
>   elements.
>
> ```
> var myFont;
>
> function preload() {
>   myFont = loadFont('assets/Avenir.otf');
> }
>
> function setup() {
>   var myDiv = createDiv('hello there');
>   myDiv.style('font-family', 'Avenir');
> }
> ```

The problem is that you're using the name of the variable to set the DOM element's font, which won't work. You need to use the name of the actual font.

```
var robotoReg = loadFont("Roboto-Regular.ttf");
document.getElementById("mStockOne").style.fontFamily = "Roboto";
```